# Weird characters in PluggableAuth button text

Tags: mediawiki

I'm running Mediawiki 1.34 and i customized the PluggableAuth login button text using `$wgPluggableAuth_ButtonLabelMessage = 'Login with ABC credentials' ;`.

But, it is adding a weird character to the beginning and end of the text.  Is that normal, can i get rid of them?

[image]

My Mediawiki is running on a Debian 10 box (with LDAP) and i get the same result whether i use Chrome, Firefox, or IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PluggableAuth) shows that i should have used `$wgPluggableAuth_ButtonLabel = 'Login with ABC credentials';` instead of using `$wgPluggableAuth_ButtonLabelMessage`.

Answer (score 2):

That variable takes a message key, not plain text. If you don't care about internationalization at all, you could set it to `new RawMessage( 'Login with ABC credentials' )`; otherwise set it to something like `'mysite-pluggableauth-button'` and then you can (alongside a number of other methods) provide the text via the `MediaWiki:mysite-pluggableauth-button/<language code>` wiki pages.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried `$wgPluggableAuth_ButtonLabelMessage = new RawMessage( 'Login with ABC credentials' );` and am getting the same result i show above.